# Image file was not found.on product tab

Tags: product, error, image

I was uploading some images from the magento backend, after so time, i got this error on my product tab.

Please help,

There has been an error processing your request
Image file was not found.

```
Trace:
#0 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('/s/c/screen_pro...')
#1 /home/camerala/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/aw_admingridimages/image.phtml(31): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'small_image')
#2 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/camerala/...')
#3 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#4 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/local/AW/Admingridimages/Block/Renderer/Image.php(44): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php(128): AW_Admingridimages_Block_Renderer_Image->render(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#8 /home/camerala/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml(161): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->getRowField(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#9 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/camerala/...')
#10 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#11 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#16 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#17 /home/camerala/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product->getGridHtml()
#18 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/camerala/...')
#19 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#20 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#24 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#26 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#28 /home/camerala/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#29 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/camerala/...')
#30 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#31 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#32 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#33 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#34 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#35 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#36 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(180): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#37 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->indexAction()
#38 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#39 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#40 /home/camerala/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#41 /home/camerala/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#42 /home/camerala/public_html/index.php(95): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: please check tab code and update that code so we can help you

Comment: just check image file in `media/catalog/product/s/c/` exist or not.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, while the file and catalog do exist and are writable by Apache user. What else could this be?

Answer (score 1):

Check file permission for your `media/catalog/product` if it is writable then check whether your image exist or not.

From your details, its seems that the image is not exist in the directory or it cannot get image from the directory `media/catalog/product/s/c/`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, while the file does exist and is writable by Apache user. What else could this be?

Comment: if it is there, then access it through url ..so you can confirm whether it is accessible or not.then let us know.

Comment: Yes, it's available via direct URL like http://myshop/media/catalog/product/m/o/bogus.jpg. It's quite big, though - 1.3M.

Comment: how it is possible?, that bogus.jpg  image should be exist in "myshop/media/catalog/product/b/o/bogus.jpg".Magento stores product images as the first two character as its parent directory .

Comment: I didn't know that and I scrambled the name. Sorry for confusion. "mo" are the real first letters.

Comment: have you posted a question for this?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out, This order contains a product which no longer exists in database. Error "**Image file was not found**" resolved after adding image place holder under:

> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Product Image Placeholders and upload Base,
>   Small image and Thumbnail

Once uploaded, view back your order. The product which no longer exists will have this placeholder image.

I hope this will help someone for same issue. :-)